# wrap/comment comments

Tags: c, comments

I copy this struct

```
typedef struct SDL_Surface {
Uint32 flags; /* Read-only */
SDL_PixelFormat *format; /* Read-only */
int w, h; /* Read-only */
Uint16 pitch; /* Read-only */
void *pixels; /* Read-write */
SDL_Rect clip_rect; /* Read-only */
8 int refcount; /* Read-mostly */
/* This structure also contains private fields not shown
here */} SDL_Surface;
```

and tried to comment(wrap) out with /* and */ and beginning and end of the codes but it wouldn't work.

```
/*
typedef struct SDL_Surface { //only commented out this line
Uint32 flags; /* Read-only */
SDL_PixelFormat *format; /* Read-only */ 
int w, h; /* Read-only */
Uint16 pitch; /* Read-only */
void *pixels; /* Read-write */
SDL_Rect clip_rect; /* Read-only */
8 int refcount; /* Read-mostly */
/* This structure also contains private fields not shown
here */} SDL_Surface;
*/
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does C permits nested comments like /* ... /* .. */ ... */ ?

Comment: Also, what is that "8" near `refcount`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
#if 0
blah
#endif
```

to "comment out" large blocks of code like that. It also has the benefit of being nestable.

(The reason `/*` and `*/` aren't working is because once inside a comment, the *first* `*/` will end it, so `/* blah /* explanation */ more */` will end after `explanation`, *not* `more`)

Answer (score 1):

Nesting comments doesn't work, but you can have the preprocessor skip the struct

```
#if 0

    typedef struct SDL_Surface {
    Uint32 flags; /* Read-only */
    SDL_PixelFormat *format; /* Read-only */
    int w, h; /* Read-only */
    Uint16 pitch; /* Read-only */
    void *pixels; /* Read-write */
    SDL_Rect clip_rect; /* Read-only */
    8 int refcount; /* Read-mostly */
    /* This structure also contains private fields not shown
    here */} SDL_Surface;

#endif
```